# Having issue with angular filter in order to search through list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular filter in order to search through the list. Searching using filter is working fine but issue is along with i also have a check box('Select All') this check box is also perfoming its action fine but when i search through the list and if i get only two element out of six and then i check my 'Select box' the other four elements in rows also get checked . I want to avoid this situation . My code is below:

Html

```
<select-all-checkbox checkboxes="editResource.allowedUsersList" all-selected="allSelectedWtUsers" all-clear="noSelectedWtUsers" multiple="multipleWtUsers" ids="selectedWUsersIds"></select-all-checkbox>
    <input type='text' ng-model="name" placeholder="search"/>
    <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="allowedUser in editResource.allowedUsersList | filter:{firstName:name}"></div>
```

Directive:
This directive is used to select checkboxes.

```
directive('selectAllCheckbox', function () {
                        return {
                            replace: true,
                            restrict: 'E',
                            scope: {
                                checkboxes: '=',
                                allselected: '=allSelected',
                                allclear: '=allClear',
                                multiple: '=multiple',
                                ids: '=ids'
                            },
                            template: '<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" ng-model="master" ng-change="masterChange()">',
                            controller: function ($scope, $element) {
                                $scope.masterChange = function () {
                                    if ($scope.master) {
                                        angular.forEach($scope.checkboxes, function (cb, index) {
                                            cb.isSelected = true;
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        angular.forEach($scope.checkboxes, function (cb, index) {
                                            cb.isSelected = false;
                                        });
                                    }
                                };
                                $scope.$watch('checkboxes', function (newVal,oldVal) {
                                    if(newVal !== oldVal){
                                         var allSet = true,allClear = true,countSelected = 0;
                                            $scope.ids = [];
                                            angular.forEach($scope.checkboxes, function (cb, index) {
                                                if(cb.isSelected){
                                                    countSelected ++;
                                                    $scope.ids.push(cb.id);
                                                }
                                                if (cb.isSelected) {
                                                    allClear = false;
                                                } else {
                                                    allSet = false;
                                                }
                                            });
                                            if(countSelected > 1){
                                                $scope.multiple = true
                                            }else{
                                                $scope.multiple = false
                                            }
                                            if ($scope.allselected !== undefined) {
                                                $scope.allselected = allSet;
                                            }
                                            if ($scope.allclear !== undefined) {
                                                $scope.allclear = allClear;
                                            }

                                            $element.prop('indeterminate', false);
                                            if (allSet) {
                                                $scope.master = true;
                                            } else if (allClear) {
                                                $scope.master = false;
                                            } else {
                                                $scope.master = false;
                                                $element.prop('indeterminate', true);
                                            }
                                    }
                                }, true);
                            }
                        };
                    });
```

Basically I want if i search my list of items and my item list length is 20 and i am getting 4 items using filter then my list should be of size 4 and if i clear my search box then my item list should again becomes of size 20.

Most important point is if i getting 4 items after pressing some keys into search box and if i delete 1 item and again clear my search box then i should get 19 items of my list.

Hope you understand my issue. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: You can try to watch the search input changes to flag the currently available list to select all instead of iterating the whole list.

Comment: I got the partial solution of this using this code: item in datalist = (myList | filter:name). This helps me to change the size of list if type in search box. but i want that if press 'select all ' button then i want only four rows to be selected not all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with a controller (filtering the list in the controller):

http://codepen.io/jlowcs/pen/YPvvMX

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
  <label><select-all-checkbox checkboxes="filteredList" all-selected="allSelectedWtUsers" all-clear="noSelectedWtUsers" multiple="multipleWtUsers" ids="selectedWUsersIds"></select-all-checkbox>select all</label>
  <br>
  <input type='text' ng-model="name" placeholder="search"/>
  <br>
  Filtered:
  <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="allowedUser in filteredList">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allowedUser.isSelected"> {{allowedUser.firstName}} {{allowedUser.lastName}}
  </div>
  <br>
  All:
  <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="allowedUser in editResource.allowedUsersList">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allowedUser.isSelected"> {{allowedUser.firstName}} {{allowedUser.lastName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
angular.module('exampleApp', [])
.controller('exampleCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.editResource = {
    allowedUsersList: [
      {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Smith', isSelected: false},
      {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Parker', isSelected: false},
      {firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Smith', isSelected: false}
    ]
  };

  $scope.$watch('name', function () {
    $scope.filteredList = $scope.$eval('editResource.allowedUsersList | filter:{firstName:name}');  
  })  
})
.directive('selectAllCheckbox', function () {
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      checkboxes: '=',
      allselected: '=allSelected',
      allclear: '=allClear',
      multiple: '=multiple',
      ids: '=ids'
    },
    template: '<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" ng-model="master" ng-change="masterChange()">',
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
      $scope.masterChange = function () {
        if ($scope.master) {
          angular.forEach($scope.checkboxes, function (cb, index) {
            cb.isSelected = true;
          });
        } else {
         angular.forEach($scope.checkboxes, function (cb, index) {
            cb.isSelected = false;
          });
        }
      };
      $scope.$watchCollection('checkboxes', function (newVal,oldVal) {
        if(newVal !== oldVal){
          var allSet = true,allClear = true,countSelected = 0;
          $scope.ids = [];
          angular.forEach($scope.checkboxes, function (cb, index) {
            if(cb.isSelected){
              countSelected ++;
              $scope.ids.push(cb.id);
            }
            if (cb.isSelected) {
              allClear = false;
            } else {
              allSet = false;
            }
          });
          if(countSelected > 1){
            $scope.multiple = true
          }else{
            $scope.multiple = false
          }
          if ($scope.allselected !== undefined) {
            $scope.allselected = allSet;
          }
          if ($scope.allclear !== undefined) {
            $scope.allclear = allClear;
          }

          $element.prop('indeterminate', false);
          if (allSet) {
            $scope.master = true;
          } else if (allClear) {
            $scope.master = false;
          } else {
            $scope.master = false;
            $element.prop('indeterminate', true);
          }
        }
      }, true);
    }
  };
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['exampleApp']);
```

Comment: I also used $watchCollection instead of $watch. $watch will watch the array's reference, while $watchCollection will watch its content.